# Update MySQL columns based on other columns

Tags: mysql, database, find-replace

So, I have a members table that we'll call **table_members**. Among others, it has a column called **email**.

There's also a table called **table_oldnewemail**. It has two columns: **old_email** and **new_email**.

I'd like to:
1. Find the row in table_members where table_members.email equals table_oldnewemail.old_email
2. Then replace table_members.email with the corresponding table_oldnewemail.new_email
3. Repeat for all table_oldnewemail values

I feel I have all the necessary parts, but is this even possible with a MySQL query? What would be an otherwise smart way to automate such a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
UPDATE table_members t INNER JOIN
       table_oldnewemail tno
       ON t.email = tno.old_email
    SET t.email = tno.new_email;
```

Comment: You nailed it! And you've made my day that much better.